# Android sync data to internat storage with Retrofit Service

Tags: java, android, data-synchronization

I want to have some data stored in Device in order my application to work offline. They are plain java objects that are returned from a JSON web service. I use retrofit + GSON . The issue is how to store them.

**WHAT I have tried**
Tried to use Serializable interface at my java classes and during my sync()  method when I fetch them from webservice I store them at a file.  Performance is a bit poor at slow devices during sync. Not much but it is an issue.

**WHAT I attempted**
I attemted to store JSON from Response Retrofit. However  it seems a bit of pain. Because it doesnt return as string the result but as InputStream. Then I have to convert back again.

**WHAT I didnt do**
I didnt try SQLite and any ORM. Seems overkill to me for 7 simple list of readonly List of objects. And I guess that performance is going to suffer more.

In IOS core data is easy to achieve this out of the box. Is there a solution for this in android ?

Answer (score 0):

Best approach to this is to write the JSON out to a file using one of the near infinite number of free libraries or code samples, such as:  http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json.